Turning on code assistant causes storyboard to disappear
I've had an issue for awhile now where typing ctrl-option-command-enter (to bring up the code assistant) sometimes causes my storyboard to disappear. No canvas, no blue outlines, no bottom bar with devices/traits/etc, no error message, just a totally blank gray.
I've tried all the normal stuff, clearing derived data, rebooting, uninstalling/reinstalling Xcode.
The only workaround I've found is creating a new workspace and reimporting all my projects. This will restore the storyboards but only temporarily, sometimes for a week, sometimes for 10 minutes. I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this behavior and if so, if anyone has found a better fix?
Running Xcode 16.

What is your question?

I have added a question mark to make it more clear.

This sounds like a bug in Xcode. The thing to do, is to report this to Apple as a bug report. There isn't anything we can do about it.

I'm not asking anyone to dive into the Xcode binary, just if anyone has encountered the issue and if they have any workarounds or perhaps shed light on why it might be happening. I don't think thats outside the purview of an SO question.
